# XCode 4.2 + Iphone 3g can't run app

Tags: iphone, xcode4, cordova

When I created a plain vanilla Phonegap application and try to run it on an iPhone 3g with IOS 4.2 it doesn't run. The IOS deployment target is set to 4.0 and everything does build successfully

This all happened after I installed XCode 4.2 with IOS SDK5. Running apps on the simulator is no problem.

Anyone who knows how I can get it running again?

Comment: iOS5 and Xcode 4.2 are both under NDA. You're better off asking in the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: XCode 4.2 and iOS SDK5 are 1.) beta software and should not be used for actual development 2.) under NDA. I'd suggest not to talk too loud about it.

Comment: Thanks, I downgraded back to XCode 4.1 from the app store and now it works again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See my answer to [Is it possible to target older iOS versions when using Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760946/possible-to-target-older-ios-versions-when-using-xcode-4-2-and-ios-5-sdk)