# Apps building with Xcode 4.2 could not be installed in iPhone 3G

Tags: xcode, ios4, build

I create a brand new **Single View Application** iPhone app in Xcode 4.2, it only shows the gray  screen.

When I build the app, I get the warning:

```
BWARN]warning: iPhone apps with a deployment target lower than 4.3 should include an armv6 architecture (current IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = "3.0", ARCHS = "armv7").
```

I followed [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810205/iphone-apps-with-a-deployment-target-lower-than-4-3-should-include-an-armv6-arch) , [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955987/xcode-4-2-iphone-3g-cant-run-app) and [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760946/possible-to-target-older-ios-versions-when-using-xcode-4-2-and-ios-5-sdk) to fix the warning.

My build settings are:

- Architectures: **armv6, armv7**
- Base SDK: **Latest iOS (iOS 5.0)**
- iOS Deployment Target: **iOS 3.0**

The **Required device capabilities** values in the Info.plist are **armv6, armv7**.

I make an Ad Hoc distribution of the app (this app only shows a gray screen) and put it on iTunes.

1. When I installed the app into 2 iPhone4 (one having iOS 4, one having iOS 5), it works fine.
2. When I installed the app into iPhone 3GS (having iOS 4), it works fine.
3. But
   when I try to install the app into 2 iPhone 3G (one having iOS 4.2.1, one having iOS 3.0),
   the app was not installed and I received this message.

**The app "SingleViewApplication" was not installed on the iPhone XXXXX because it is not compatible with this iPhone.**

Do you know how to make iPhone 3G be able to run apps build with Xcode 4.2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I delete the **Required device capabilities** entry in the Info.plist
and the app can be installed in iPhone 3G.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me, too. I'm on Xcode 4.3.2 and my target is iOS 4.0.